# copy text from one textbox to another on checkbox event asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two address fields which has 46 textboxes and each one accepts only one character.

For eg.

Address

Line1 : 1.2.3.4....46

Line2 : 1.2.3.4...46

Now on checkbox oncheckchanged event,

I want to copy each character from textbox to another respectively and if checkbox is not checked then line one should be remained as it is.

How to accomplish this?

I tried googling but didn't help much.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="line1_1" MaxLength="1" ></asp:TextBox><br/>
```

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="if_same" Text="Same" OnCheckedChanged="if_same_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="line2_1" MaxLength="1" ></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="line2_46" MaxLength="1" ></asp:TextBox>

protected void if_same_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
set_per_local(); 
} 

public void set_per_local() 
{ 
if (if_same.Checked == true) 
{ 
checkIfNullEmpty(); 
disablelocal(); 

string line1_address = string.Concat(line1_1.Text,line1_46.Text); 
try
{   
for (int i = 0; i < line1_address.Length; i++) 
{ 
line2_1.Text = line1_address[0].ToString(); 
line2_46.Text = line1_address[45].ToString(); 
} 
} 
catch (Exception) 
{   
throw; 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
Enablelocal(); 
} 
}  

public void checkIfNullEmpty() 
{ 
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line1_1.Text)) line1_1.Text = " "; 
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line1_46.Text)) line1_46.Text = " "; 
} 

public void disablelocal() 
{ 
local_line1_address1.Enabled = false; 
local_line1_address46.Enabled = false; 
} 

public void enablelocal()
 { 
local_line1_address1.Enabled = true;
local_line1_address46.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Comment: Did you try AutoPostBack=true?

Comment: Yes, but on page load I set default space to all textbox so when checkbox is unchecked all textboxes become empty.

Comment: what you are wanting to do is not that difficult. what have you actually tried on your own vs expecting someone to give you / code the solution for you.. please show us what you have done. also why would you have 46  textboxes for only 2 address fields.. is this a homework assignment.. ?

Comment: @MethodMan I have to concatenate each text value onto one string and insert to db.

Comment: @MethodMan sorry I don't know how to format code here

Comment: you must not follow directions very well.. do not post code as comments edit your original question and put that code there.. just paste it in the original question and I can edit it for you also if you are going to `Concat` into one string.. look up how to use `string.Concat() of string.Join()` methods too

Comment: Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38466043/edit) link and add your code to your question. Do not say things like “I tried googling” unless your problem is in using Google.

Comment: @MethodMan I edited the question

Comment: @Dour High Arch sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this site more helpful.

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/3125-how-to-copy-textbox---text-to-another-one.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox3" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox4" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="CheckBox1"  Text="Same as above" onclick="CopyText()" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="iBox1" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="iBox2" MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="iBox3"  MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="iBox4"  MaxLength="1" size="1"></asp:TextBox>

<script type="text/javascript">
function CopyText() {
var cb = document.getElementById('CheckBox1');
var tb1 = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
 var tb2 = document.getElementById('TextBox2');
  var tb3 = document.getElementById('TextBox3');
var tb4 = document.getElementById('TextBox4');
        var tb11 = document.getElementById('iBox1');
        var tb12 = document.getElementById('iBox2');
        var tb13 = document.getElementById('iBox3');
        var tb14 = document.getElementById('iBox4');
if (cb.checked) {
            tb11.value = tb1.value;
            tb12.value = tb2.value;
            tb13.value = tb3.value;
            tb14.value = tb4.value;  } 
 else {
            tb11.value = '';
            tb12.value = '';
            tb13.value = '';
            tb14.value = '';   }
}
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be a better candidate for a client-side javascript or jQuery etc.  Also, if you have followed a logical pattern for naming those 46 textboxes, in your javascript you could hook into the checkbox.changed event and start a loop walking each of the source fields and replace the target field textbox with the source value.  Something like

```
<script>
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
   if(this.checked) {
      alltextboxes();
   }
});

function copy alltextboxes()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++)
   {
      document.getElementById(tgtTbox+i).value = document.getElementById(srcTbox+i).value
   }
}
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code though. I just typed it into the answer.  based on your requirement, this code may need small modifications.  Just note that this only works if your naming convention for the textbox labels follow a pattern (like "SourceText1, SourceText2, TargetText1, TargetText2 etc.").